# Connecting to the Skubana API

Tags: rest, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, postman

Has anybody made a REST connection to Skubana before? I have the app Key and Secret, but there is no more documentation about the handshake. I'm using Postman. Any insights into connecting to their API would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After creating an App with Skubana I got an email which told me to create a trial account and then how to install the app on the trial account.  There is then a further process to get the token which is required to access that trial account via the API.  I have not seen those instructions anywhere except in the email.  The API documentation is a little terse.